# prototype setAttribute() not working with $$() selector

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

I want to change the button onclick function inside a div. The HTML code is as bellow

```
<div class="buttons-set" id="payment-buttons-container">
    <button type="button" class="button" onclick="payment.save()" id="payment_button"></button>
</div>
```

I am using the following prototype to change the onlick function payment.save() to something else.

```
if(payment_method=='gate') {
   var e = $$('div#payment-buttons-container button.button');
   e.setAttribute('onclick','return false;'); // not working
} else {
    var e = $$('div#payment-buttons-container button.button');
    e.setAttribute('onclick','payment.save();'); // not working
}
```

Which is not working and saying "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object HTMLButtonElement] has no method 'setAttribute'"But when i am using this code by taking the id of the button statically, than its working

```
if(payment_method=='gate') {
    $('payment_button').setAttribute('onclick','return false;');// Works
}
else {
    $('payment_button').setAttribute('onclick','payment.save();');// Works
}
```

Where "payment_button" is the ID of the button which i taken.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is that `$$()` returns a list of elements that match the CSS selector

try this if you just want the first element the matches the selector

```
if(payment_method=='gate') {
   var e = $$('div#payment-buttons-container button.button')[0];
   e.setAttribute('onclick','return false;'); // not working
} else {
   var e = $$('div#payment-buttons-container button.button')[0];
   e.setAttribute('onclick','payment.save();'); // not working
}
```

if you want to apply it to all the elements that the CSS selector matches do it this way using the `invoke()` method

```
if(payment_method=='gate') {
   $$('div#payment-buttons-container button.button').invoke('writeAttribute','onclick','return false;');
} else {
    $$('div#payment-buttons-container button.button').invoke('writeAttribute','onclick','payment.save();'); // not working
}
```

the reason I used `writeAttribute()` instead of `setAttribute()` is that `writeAttribute()` is the PrototypeJS method and will work across all the browsers that PrototypeJS supports, `setAttbribute()` is the standard method that is not always available.

Comment: Thank a lot. It solved all the issue. Thanks for such support.